# JPanels one above the other

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to design a jFrame where there are three jButtons and a set of three jpanels one above the other. When we call a jPanel from the respective jButton , that pane will be displayed. It would appear to the user as if the same portion of the jFrame is displaying the content to be shown on clicking each jButton.But when i am trying to set the jPanels one above the other, they are being shown side by side thus elongating the jFrame horizontally. What should i do to put one jPanel over the other? Any other idea than jPanel which should do the work i intend to do would also be help !!

Comment: your codes broww ?, please post your codes to appreciate others who struggling understanding & answering your question.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of how the GUI should appear at default size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.  A before/after button is clicked view would also be helpful.

Comment: A `JTabbedPane` could do the trick as well (although the headers don't look like `JButton`)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your behavior sounds like you are using a `FlowLayout`. This will not "layer" anything. Instead us a `CardLayout`, which does exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You call method like `show`, `next`, and `previous` to navigate the panels. See [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details.

Also there are probably hundreds of other examples here on so. Go through the [cardlayout](/questions/tagged/cardlayout) questions. 
<sup>[Tip: navigate the different tabs like "votes" and "frequent" to filter to some of the better posts]</sup>

Here's [one that uses the `show()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25339133/2587435) to switch between two panels by name.