# How to perform an action when a particular card is being displayed in CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout, listeners

I am having a problem in `CardLayout`. I have around 15 cards in my swing application. Some cards are there for displaying the data from database, they should run the sql and display the data. The name of a such card is "Lawyers".

But my question is, how do I know that "Lawyer" card is being displayed so I can call the database queries? I am not interested in knowing whether "Lawyer" got displayed after "Account" card or something like that, I just need to know whether it is being displayed now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see my question [JPanel which one of Listeners is proper for visibility is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880326/jpanel-which-one-of-listeners-is-proper-for-visibility-is-changed), btw answers are like as effort in your question

Comment: Maybe [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25339133/2587435).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a ComponentAdapter to your Lawyer card and implement the "componentShown()" method

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any tutorial? I have never worked with it.

Comment: @Hope probably. Look instead for "ComponentListener tutorial"

Comment: @Hope [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25339133/2587435) with CardLayout and ComponentListener